# WPF Data Grid Formatting - Not All Styles Are Honored

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**The Problem**

Styles used:

- `DataGridRow`
- `DataGridCell`

I can either get highlighting *or* cell padding to function, *but not both* at the same time. I tried many-many different approaches (e.g., resources vs. specific DataGrid styles), but nothing works and allows for question.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- DataGridRow style -->
    <Style x:Key="MyRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush 
              x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#E5BE47" />
            <SolidColorBrush 
              x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <!-- DataGridCell style -->
    <Style x:Key="MyCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Padding="15,10,10,15">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!-- BOTH styles are used, which illustrates the problem: -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="Connections" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      RowStyle="{StaticResource MyRowStyle}" 
      CellStyle="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Process Id"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Application"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Directory" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The Foreground will correctly change to "red" but the background remains white (and not yellow as defined by #E5BE47). It seems that the HighlightBrushKey is completely ignored for some reason that I don't understand when the `DataGridCell` style is also used.

This is an **AND** problem, not an **OR** problem. How to use both styles in a DataGrid? Separately, the styles work. *The problem is the combination of the two... both will not work together - why and how to resolve?*

Output left, desired output right:

[image]

If `DataGridCell` style is removed, then background color for the highlighter works correctly... but this is NOT a solution as it removes the desired padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works

```
<Style x:Key="MyRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Resources>             
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E5BE47 />
       </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but the problem reamains: it is the *combination* of highlighting and cell padding. When both styles are used (as in my demo code) then highlighting is ignored. If I, however, remove ```CellStyle="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}"``` then highlighting is honored, but I don't get the desired padding. So, there is some conflict between the two styles (DataGridCell and DataGridRow).

Comment: @ChEJunkie I edited my answer. I added trigger, it works.

Comment: Thank you @dmitriy! For anyone who comes across this question, this looks like a reasonable resource for more information on the solution: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xaml/xaml_triggers.htm